# Reading serial port data with buffer

Tags: c#, serial-port, buffer

I want to read data from a serial port and store it in `buffer`.

I searched and could not find a solution as to how to store it in buffer.

Below is my program so far. The received data is being converted to Hex.

So now I just need the buffer part working.

Thank you

```
static SerialPort myserialPort;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


       myserialPort = new SerialPort("COM8", 9600);

        myserialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(myserialPort_DataReceived);

        try
        {
            myserialPort.Open();


        }

        catch 
        {

        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to close...");  
        Console.ReadLine(); / this is just so i can hold the console open

    }

    private static void myserialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string bytestr = "";

        int numbytes = myserialPort.BytesToRead;
        byte[] rxbytearray = new byte[numbytes];

        for (int i = 0; i < numbytes; i++)
        {
            rxbytearray[i] = (byte)myserialPort.ReadByte();
        }

        string hexvalues = "";
        foreach (byte b in rxbytearray)
        {
            if (b != '\r')
                hexvalues = hexvalues + (b.ToString()) + " ";


        }       //  hexvalues = richTextBox1.Text;

        Console.WriteLine(hexvalues);

        //MessageBox.Show(hexvalues);



    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by `buffer`?  Like an `Array`? Or a `List`?  It's confusing what you are asking for, can you clarify?  Do you want to save the hex?  A simpler solution might be to save the strings.

Comment: i resolved the problem , thank you for commenting